# How to handle unusual characters in a csv read operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a very large Excel spreadsheet where the data need to be pivoted into columns etc and no problems excepting that it is full of some very odd characters from French, Portuguese.  The Panda data frame copes with out any problems until I need to output the data as a csv file

```
dframe.to_csv(csvf, header=False)
sourceFile = open(csvf, 'r')
csvdata = sourceFile.read()
with open('output.csv', 'a') as destFile:
    destFile.write(csvdata)
sourceFile.close()
```

This produces an error at line 3:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 3184: character maps to undefined
```

This I tracked to a field in the data containing `TTD ChÃ”teauneuf-du-Pape 75cl` - specifically it is this character `”` which is, according to a Unicode identifier, "U+201D : RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK {double comma quotation mark}"

I have tried to remove this in the data frame itself with:

```
df[self.data_columns[i]] = df[self.data_columns[i]].str.replace('”',' ')
```

But it didn't seem to do anything NB a similar line successfully strips out unwanted commas.

Is there any way of handling the `read()` problem so it can cope with any character?  What I find odd is that the rest of the system e.g. loading the data in to a data frame, manipulating the data is all fine

Comment: Try adding `encoding="utf-8"` to `to_csv()` and both `open()` commands. If you view the file, you need to use an application that can handle utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Yup that worked - thank you very much